# error variance (delta) of a factor - lavaan

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, reliability, lavaan

I'm building a measurement model with three factors and I don't know how to set the error variance ((1 - reliability) * item's variance) of one of the factors in lavaan. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If there is a lavaan support forum you might be better off there.

Comment: request for clarification: ¿are you estimating the reliability from the model? or ¿is this a value you have predetermined?

Comment: I have a model with 3 factors (m1 =~ a + b + c) and lavaan returns me negative variances, so to improve my model estimation, I would like to fix the variance of an error for factor "a". I've computed split-half reliability of "a".

Answer (score 1):

If a = 0.73 is the reliability estimate, and the latent factor is latfact, then first calculate

```
a <- 0.73
1-a^2
```

0.4671
 
This is necessary because you can't pass variables into lavaan thru the model.
Next, add the following line to the model

```
latfact ~~ 0.4671*latfact
```

This should fix the variance

I hope this helps.